# web3 get name from address

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, metamask

```
import Web3 from "web3";


useEffect(() => {
const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);

web3.eth.ens.getAddress("ethereum.eth").then(function (address) {
    console.log(address);
});
}, []);
```

here using this code I am getting `address` from ether name
is there any way I can get name from address

```
web3.eth.ens.getOwner("0xc74E8eFaFE54481bD109f97422AeBca607499f57").then(function (address) {
    console.log(address);
});
```

I am trying above piece of code but it is not working
if I input `0xc74E8eFaFE54481bD109f97422AeBca607499f57`

I should get `ethereum.eth`

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the [ENS documentation](https://docs.ens.domains/dapp-developer-guide/resolving-names), web3.js can't perform "reversed resolution", i.e. getting a ENS name from an address. However, you can do this from the [ensjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ensdomains/ensjs) API like this:

```
const address = '0xc74E8eFaFE54481bD109f97422AeBca607499f57';
var name = await ens.getName(address)
// Check to be sure the reverse record is correct.
if(address != await ens.name(name).getAddress()) {
  name = null;
}
```